# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.3 app though model relations seems appropriate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    public function enrollments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\enrollments','user_email');
    }
}
```

Batch model

```
class batch extends Model{
    protected $table = 'batch';
    public function enrollments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\enrollments');
    }
}
```

Enrollments model

```
class enrollments extends Model{
    public function batch() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\batch');
    }
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','email');
    }
}
```

if I use $enrollment->batch->title, it works..
but if I use $enrollment->user->name, it gives an error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Please help, I am stuck
Thanks in advance

EDIT

The problem arose after I changed the foreign key from between user and enrollment from id to email and renamed my column to user_email from user_id. Before that code was working fine.

Solved

Got the problem, It was with some data in enrollment which didn't have registered email with user.

Comment: Go to `tinker` and try `$enrollment->user`. If you get null then there's no entry in the database for the column `email`. Are you sure your foreign key is indeed `email`?

Comment: Can you please guide me through the tinker process? and yes foreign key is email in relation view in phpmyadmin also.

Answer (score 0):

This code will note work simply because **User is not a child of Model**. To fix it you must extend from `Model`. `Authenticatable` is an `interface` and there is an equivalent `trait`; there is no such class.

You must implement the interface if you want your user class to be Authenticatable. But to answer your question, extend the base model, `Model`.

```
   class User extends Model {
    public function enrollments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\enrollments','user_email');
    }}
```

**In addition:**

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application,
>   you may call the login method with the user instance. The given object
>   must be an implementation of the 
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. Of course, the
>   App\User model included with Laravel already implements this
>   interface:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

Comment: Authenticable extends Model by default, I just checked

Comment: and code used to work fine before I changed the foreign key

Comment: no you are wrong...[Read Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#the-authenticatable-contract).   `Authenticatable` is an `interface` and there is an equivalent `trait`. There is no such class. Therefore you cannot extend it how you are trying.

Comment: Got the problem, it wasn't with authenticable. It was with some data in enrollment which didn't have registered email with user.

Comment: Now its working fine even model extends authenticable